# FastAI appends `models/` prefix and `.pth` suffix to weights file path

Tags: python-3.x, fast-ai, filenotfounderror

Goal: Override FastAI appending `models/` prefix and `.pth` suffix to the **weights** file path.

Version: `fastai==2.7.7`

Note: this behaviour does not happen to the **model** file path.

How can I override this behaviour?

Turning:

```
model.load('data/models/my_weights.pth')
```

Into:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models/data/models/my_weights.pth.pth'
```

---

Code:

```
def inference(model_params: ModelParams, device: str, dataloader: DataLoader, id: str):
    model = load_learner(model_params.model, cpu=device=='cpu')
    model.load('data/models/my_weights.pth')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/BitBucket/project/app/container/main.py", line 145, in <module>
    prediciton = inference(model_params, device, dataloader, id)
  File "/home/me/BitBucket/project/app/container/main.py", line 116, in inference
    model.load('data/models/my_weights.pth')
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/learner.py", line 387, in load
    load_model(file, self.model, self.opt, device=device, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastai/learner.py", line 51, in load_model
    state = torch.load(file, map_location=device)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 791, in load
    with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 271, in _open_file_like
    return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 252, in __init__
    super().__init__(open(name, mode))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models/data/models/my_weights.pth.pth'
```

Comment: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/issues/3914)

Comment: What is `model_params.model` exactly? I've checked fastai and torch code, none of them change input path. There is something to notice. `model.load(path)` calls the `load(path)` method from `fname`. `fname` is the first input of `load_learner (fname, cpu=True)`. So we can conclude the bug is from your `model_params.model`'s `load` method.

Comment: `model_params.model` is just the file path for the model .pkl. This path does not have this problem. Ohh interesting ok, I'll wrap my head around this more and get back here tomorrow

Comment: Passing the string literal directly `model.load('data/models/my_weights.pth')` still throws: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models/data/models/my_weights.pth.pth'`

Comment: Seems like in the class, the path is appened with .pth. This can not be prevented, exept for altering the libary.   ` file = join_path_file(file, self.path/self.model_dir, ext='.pth')`

Comment: Can you please provide more code for this @DanielBell99 I cannot reproduce the error and by adding print functions to the libraries ***DO NOT DO IT UNLESS 1000% SURE*** I cannot seem to find anywhere that changes the path.